# How to use binded function to "this" in html? Style guide angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide convention.

Inside section **Function Declarations to Hide Implementation Details**

How to use function in side html when i bind it to `this` like:

```
function AvengersCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.activate = activate;


    function activate() {
        alert("activate");
    }
}
```

and use it in html:

```
<body ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">...
    <button ng-click="activate()"></button>
</body>
```

when i use `scope` instead of `this` it works

```
$scope.activate = activate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body ng-controller="AvengersCtrl as aveng">...
<button ng-click="aveng.activate()"></button>
</body>
```

if you don't specify an alias for the controller (as i have done with 'aveng') and you don't call your function with alias.function() syntax, angular will look for an 'activate()' function inside your global functions, not inside your AvengersCtrl object

Answer (score 2):

You need to use what's known as *[controller as](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example)* syntax:

```
<body ng-controller="AvengersCtrl as ctrl">...
    <button ng-click="ctrl.activate()"></button>
</body>
```